# CSS animation is shaking in firefox

Tags: html, css, animation

I've written some pulse animation but it don't work properly. This image terribly shaking in Firefox browser only. What can i do to prevent it?

---

```css
.heart::before {
    content: "\f004";
    color: #E98E1B;
}

.pulseHeart {
    -webkit-animation: pulseHeart 1s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: pulseHeart 1s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: pulseHeart 1s linear infinite;
    animation: pulseHeart 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes "pulseHeart" {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
        -o-transform: scale(1.1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
        -o-transform: scale(0.8);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

}

@-moz-keyframes pulseHeart {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    50% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

}

@-webkit-keyframes "pulseHeart" {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

}

@-ms-keyframes "pulseHeart" {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    50% {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <title>page</title>
  <body>
    <span class="fa heart pulseHeart"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've seen some code snippets on Stack but they didn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall to add initial value for `transform` property.

```css
.heart::before {
    content: "\f004";
    color: #E98E1B;
}

.pulseHeart {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1); // !!! NEW LINE !!!
    -moz-transform: scale(1); // !!! LINE !!!
    -o-transform: scale(1); // !!! LINE !!!
    -ms-transform: scale(1); // !!! LINE !!!
    transform: scale(1); // !!! LINE !!!
    -webkit-animation: pulseHeart 1s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: pulseHeart 1s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: pulseHeart 1s linear infinite;
    animation: pulseHeart 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes "pulseHeart" {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
        -o-transform: scale(1.1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
        -o-transform: scale(0.8);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

}

@-moz-keyframes pulseHeart {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    50% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

}

@-webkit-keyframes "pulseHeart" {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

}

@-ms-keyframes "pulseHeart" {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    50% {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <title>page</title>
  <body>
    <span class="fa heart pulseHeart"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AnastasiaAntontseva Actually i don't know but it helps me. I think there is more elegant solution.

Comment: this snippet is also shaking in FF.
If you want a smooth animation, you better scale from 1 to 0.8 to 1.
no need to set initial values

http://codepen.io/janwagner/pen/LbYMyR

Comment: @Cherrypig thank you but snippet above helps me and i fixed this bug.